# Unable to see available devices in bluetooth app using broadcast receiver

Tags: kotlin, mobile-application

I am currently working on a Bluetooth application in Android, and I have encountered an issue that I am struggling to resolve. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the community.

The problem I am facing is that, despite initiating a Bluetooth device discovery process, I cannot see the list of available devices in my app. I have set up breakpoints in my code, and I noticed that the onReceive method of my BroadcastReceiver is not being executed.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
class DeviceListActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var mBtAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private lateinit var mNewDevicesArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list)

        // Initialize array adapter for paired devices
        val pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name)

        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.device_name)

        val scanButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_scan)
        scanButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "Button Clicked")

            doDiscovery()
            it.visibility = View.GONE
//            mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear()
        }

        val pairedListView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.paired_devices)
        pairedListView.adapter = pairedDevicesArrayAdapter
        pairedListView.onItemClickListener = mDeviceClickListener

        val newDevicesListView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.new_devices)
        newDevicesListView.adapter = mNewDevicesArrayAdapter
        newDevicesListView.onItemClickListener = mDeviceClickListener

        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter)

        Log.d("TAG", "Receiver registered")


        val filter2 = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2)

        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        // Check for Bluetooth permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Handle Bluetooth permission request
            return
        }

        val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = mBtAdapter.bondedDevices
        if (pairedDevices.isNotEmpty()) {
            findViewById<View>(R.id.title_paired_devices).visibility = View.VISIBLE
            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add("${device.name}\n${device.address}")
            }
        } else {
            val noDevices = resources.getText(R.string.none_paired).toString()
            pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices)
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun doDiscovery() {

        Log.d("TAG", "doDiscovery()")

//        // Check for Bluetooth permissions
//        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
//                this,
//                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
//            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
//        ) {
//            // TODO: Handle Bluetooth permission request
//            return
//        }

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)
        title = getString(R.string.scanning)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.title_new_devices).visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
        }

        if (!mBtAdapter.isEnabled) {
            // Request the user to enable Bluetooth
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        } else {
            // Bluetooth is enabled, start discovery
            mBtAdapter.startDiscovery()
        }
    }

    private fun connectToDevice(address: String) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()


    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private val mDeviceClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, v, _, _ ->
        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery()

        val info = (v as TextView).text.toString()
        if (info.length > 17) {
            val address = info.substring(info.length - 17)
            connectToDevice(address)
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Invalid device selection.")
        }
    }

    private val mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action: String = intent.action!!
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
                Log.d("TAG", "ACTION_FOUND")
                val device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                if (device!!.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    // Check for Bluetooth permissions
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this@DeviceListActivity,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        // Request the Bluetooth permission
                        val REQUEST_CODE = 1
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            this@DeviceListActivity,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),
                            REQUEST_CODE
                        )

                    }
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add("${device.name}\n${device.address}")
                    Log.d("device", device.toString())
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED == action) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)
                title = getString(R.string.select_device)
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.count == 0) {
                    val noDevices = resources.getText(R.string.none_found).toString()
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices)
                }
                val scanButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_scan)
                scanButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver)
    }

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address"
    }
}
```

As a result, the list of available devices remains empty, impacting the functionality of my application. I have verified that the Bluetooth permissions are declared, and the Bluetooth adapter is enabled before initiating discovery.

I have also ensured that the doDiscovery() method correctly initiates the Bluetooth discovery process, and I can see the log messages related to the initiation.

I would greatly appreciate any insights into why the onReceive method might not be triggered and how to address this issue.